# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # Something

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following code inside a React Component

```
  handleClick: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var post = new AisisWriter.Models.Post()

    var title = this.stripHtml($('#post-title').val());
    var content = this.stripHtml($('#post-content').val());

    post.set({title: title, content: content});
    post.save().then(this.created, this.failed);
  },


  stripHtml: function(content){
    if($(content)[0] !== undefined){
      return $(content)[0].textContent;
    }

    return content;
  },
```

The essential point is that I am trying to strip out any HTML that you try and send back, but keep other symbols such as `#` and so on for Markdown.

Any ways, the `#post-content` contains the following: `# Something` and apparently Jquery doesn't like it: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # Something`

How can I get around this?

[JSBin of the issue](http://jsbin.com/bonojeza/5/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Can you create a demo link?

Comment: What do `#post-title` and `#post-content` have set as their values?

Comment: `#post-title` => sdfgdsf, `#post-content` => # post title

Comment: Updated post to have a jsbin

Comment: @user3379926 Could you update that jsbin to actually have jQuery as a dependency? All I get is an error that $ isn't defined.

Comment: I think its fixed? oO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me start with the solution first:

```
function stripHtml(){
  content = strip($('#content').val());
  alert(content);
}

function strip(content){
  var content2 = jQuery.parseHTML(content);
  if(content2[0].data !== undefined){
    // This will remove all the html assuming there is any
    return content2[0].data;
  }

  // Return the content if their is no html
  return content;
}
```

to explain, starting with [jQuery >= 1.9 documentation](http://stage.jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring):

> > jQuery(htmlString) versus jQuery(selectorString)
>
> Prior to 1.9, a string would be considered to be an HTML string if it
>   had HTML tags anywhere within the string. This has the potential to
>   cause inadvertent execution of code and reject valid selector strings.
>   As of 1.9, a string is only considered to be HTML if it starts with a
>   less-than ("<") character. The Migrate plugin can be used to restore
>   the pre-1.9 behavior.
>
> If a string is known to be HTML but may start with arbitrary text that
>   is not an HTML tag, pass it to jQuery.parseHTML() which will return an
>   array of DOM nodes representing the markup. A jQuery collection can be
>   created from this, for example: $($.parseHTML(htmlString)). This would
>   be considered best practice when processing HTML templates for
>   example. Simple uses of literal strings such as
>   $("
>
> Testing
>
> ").appendTo("body") are unaffected by this change.
>
> Bottom line: HTML strings passed to jQuery() that start with something
>   other than a less-than character will be interpreted as a selector.
>   Since the string usually cannot be interpreted as a selector, the most
>   likely result will be an "invalid selector syntax" error thrown by the
>   Sizzle selector engine. Use jQuery.parseHTML() to parse arbitrary
>   HTML.

and due to that you need to use [jQuery.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) function first and access your object (0) **data** element which contains the required text.